# form-data TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined with Mailgun

Tags: node.js, heroku, form-data, mailgun

I'm trying to use mailgun in my node application and I've [followed their docs](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-sending.html#examples) and have set it up like so

```
const formData = require("form-data");
const Mailgun = require("mailgun.js");
const mailgun = new Mailgun(formData);
const mg = mailgun.client({username: "api", key: "my-api-key"})

const data = {
    from: 'donotreply <mailgun@mywebsite.com>',
    to: 'an@email.com',
    subject: 'Test Subject',
    text: `Test Body`,
    attachment: [{
            filename: `a_file.pdf`,
            data: buffer
        }]
}

mg.messages.create("mywebsite.com", data)
.then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
})
```

When I test my app locally, it works perfectly, but when I test it on my heroku server, I get this error

```
2023-03-26T19:23:46.786638+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/form-data/lib/form_data.js:250
2023-03-26T19:23:46.786665+00:00 app[web.1]:   if (!contentType && value.name) {
2023-03-26T19:23:46.786665+00:00 app[web.1]:                             ^
2023-03-26T19:23:46.786666+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-03-26T19:23:46.786666+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
2023-03-26T19:23:46.786667+00:00 app[web.1]:     at FormData._getContentType (/app/node_modules/form-data/lib/form_data.js:250:29)
2023-03-26T19:23:46.786667+00:00 app[web.1]:     at FormData._multiPartHeader (/app/node_modules/form-data/lib/form_data.js:179:26)
2023-03-26T19:23:46.786668+00:00 app[web.1]:     at FormData.append (/app/node_modules/form-data/lib/form_data.js:71:21)
2023-03-26T19:23:46.786668+00:00 app[web.1]:     at i (/app/node_modules/mailgun.js/mailgun.node.js:2:33205)
2023-03-26T19:23:46.786668+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/mailgun.js/mailgun.node.js:2:33285
2023-03-26T19:23:46.786668+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
2023-03-26T19:23:46.786669+00:00 app[web.1]:     at e.addFilesToFD (/app/node_modules/mailgun.js/mailgun.node.js:2:33264)
2023-03-26T19:23:46.786669+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/mailgun.js/mailgun.node.js:2:32363
2023-03-26T19:23:46.786669+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
2023-03-26T19:23:46.786670+00:00 app[web.1]:     at e.createFormData (/app/node_modules/mailgun.js/mailgun.node.js:2:32271)
```

I've tried doing multiple things like making sure I set the servers node version to my local version (which I should do regardless I think lol) and npm installing form-data (it worked without doing that locally so I thought it's included with Node but I saw there's a package available so I installed it regardless).

Any advice is appreciated, thanks!